# Does anyone know how to turn off dSYM generation in Xcode 5?

Tags: xcode, xcode5, dsym

As the title says. I've seen instructions for previous version of Xcode but I can't figure out how to turn it off in Xcode 5.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be hidden by default in Xcode 5. Try changing the view from "basic" to "all".